# C# Hardware Info

Tags: c#, hardware

I have this code for getting the hardware information and I have two problems:

1. I can't make it to show me the ram memory and name2
2. I need a bit of explanation for the second part, to understand a bit how it works.

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

   namespace ConsoleApp1
 {
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Motherboard Manufacturer: ");
        GetComponent("Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer");
        Console.Write("Motherboard Model:");
        GetComponent("Win32_BaseBoard", "Product");
        Console.Write("CPU:");
        GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "Name");
        Console.Write("GPUs:");
        GetComponent("Win32_VideoController", "Name");
        Console.Write("BIOS Brand: ");
        GetComponent("Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer");
        Console.Write("BIOS version: ");
        GetComponent("Win32_BIOS", "Name");
        Console.Write("Audio:");
        GetComponent("Win32_SoundDevice", "ProductName");
        Console.Write("Optical Drives:");
        GetComponent("Win32_CDROMDrive", "Name");
        Console.Write("Device Name:");
        GetComponent("Win32_ComputerSystem", "Name");
        Console.Write("HDD:");
        GetComponent("Win32_DiskDrive", "Model");
        Console.Write("Network:");
        GetComponent("Win32_NetworkAdapter", "Name");
        Console.Read();


    }



    private static void GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
        foreach (ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]) != "")
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by name2 ?

Comment: The info provided by WMI (aka System.Management) is only as good as the chipset drivers provided by the manufacturer allow it to be.  Which in this era of cut-throat competition in that business segment is not much.  The question has been asked many times before, google "c# get ram modules".  Pop the case and have a look, move to the next project.

Answer (score 0):

This is partial answer.

1. For RAM ( Physical Memory) Use following class.

   ```
   Win32_PhysicalMemory
   ```

Also I suggest that instead of Name try to read Capicity ,PartNumber or Serial Number Property so it will helpful. ( Tag is also useful).

Comment: I've tried it and it shows me info about hdd, I don't know why

Comment: @Alex Badea  No, it doesn't. You have to read the "Capacity" member and multiply that value (converted to `Int64`) by the number of "DeviceLocator" fields (the number of banks the Ram modules occupy). Of course, "Capacity" can have different values, so check this before multiplying blindly. Download Microsoft's [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572). It will help when searching for WMI components fields/properties. For the Manifacturer, you have to read it's code. And have means to compare it to the registered owners.